# Using javascript, can we get elements by tag name and ids

Tags: getelementsbytagname

Suppose I have few 'SELECT' tags. Some of them have the attribute 'id' assigned and the rest of them do not. How do I get those 'SELECT' tags with non-blank 'id'?
Can this be done in a single statement like:

```
var ctrlList = document.getElementsByTagName("select").getElementsById("*");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for this:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('select[id]');
console.log(elements.length);
```

```html
<select id="something">
</select>

<select>
</select>
```

Comment: Done. Sorry I didn't know the protocol :-) Thanks again.